# Deploying azure automation account cert

Tags: azure, azure-automation

I generated a pfx blob using this script :

```
$appId = Read-Host "Enter application ID of service principal"
$adApp = (Get-AzureRmADApplication -ApplicationId $appId)[0]
$spnId = (Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalName $adApp.IdentifierUris[0])[0].Id.Guid

$endDate = (Get-Date).AddYears(1)
$certSelfSigned = New-SelfSignedCertificateEx -Subject "CN=$spnId" -StoreLocation CurrentUser -NotAfter $endDate -Exportable -Provider "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider"
$publicKey = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($certSelfSigned.GetRawCertData())
New-AzureRmADSpCredential -ServicePrincipalObjectId $spnId -CertValue $publicKey -EndDate $certSelfSigned.GetExpirationDateString()
# TEST: Login-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -CertificateThumbprint $certSelfSigned.Thumbprint -ApplicationId $appId -TenantId <guid>

$storeLocation = [Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation]::CurrentUser
$storeName = [Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName]::My
$store = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store @($storeName, $storeLocation)
$store.Open([Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]::OpenExistingOnly)
$findType = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType]::FindByThumbprint
$cert = $store.Certificates.Find($findType, $certSelfSigned.Thumbprint, $false)
$pfxBlob = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cert.Export([Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Pkcs12))
$store.Close()

"THUMBPRINT: $($certSelfSigned.Thumbprint)"
"PFX BLOB: `n$pfxBlob"
```

I copied the pfx blob and made a .pfx file and in azure portal when I create a new certificate for an automation account and upload the file I created before it gives me internal server error.

What is the correct format of .pfx file and what is the password that I will be using to set and how will I use a thumbprint?